# How can I make vlc play all videos at 50% volume?

Tags: vlc

Is there a way I can make vlc play  all videos at 50% volume by default? I looked at the online documentation but it didn't say if there is a configuration file I could tweak.

Is there any way, by editing a configuration file or any other method, to set vlc's default volume to 50%?

Comment: I changed your question since you're not really interested in a yes/no answer about whether vlc has a configuration file, you seem to be asking about setting the default volume. By the way, yes, it does: `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's be lazy: this can be done using the GUI. Which GUI to use however depends on the audio output system you're using. Open VLC, and go to *Tools > Preferences > Audio*. The *Output module* setting will tell you what you're using.

- **If you're using Pulse**, then your default volume level is handled by Pulse itself. The easiest way to configure that is to use `pavucontrol`. Install it using your package manager, start VLC (with audio), and open `pavucontrol`. Get to the *Playback* tab, and set VLC's new value (in your case, 50%).
- **If you're using ALSA**, you can set your value in VLC directly. Just above the *Output module* option, check the *Always reset audio start level to* box, and select 50% in the slider next to it.

---

If you want to configure the volume level without using VLC/pavucontrol, then again, the method depends on your audio output. Let's have a look at VLC's code:

```
static int getDefaultAudioVolume(vlc_object_t *obj, const char *aout)
{
    if (!strcmp(aout, "pulse"))
        return -1;
    else if (!strcmp(aout, "alsa") && module_exists("alsa"))
        return cbrtf(config_GetFloat(obj, "alsa-gain")) * 100.f + .5f;
    else if (!strcmp(aout, "sndio"))
        return -1;
    return -1;
}
```

I've simplified it a bit, but basically:

**If you're using Pulse**, VLC's configuration has no impact. You'll need to configure Pulse itself. Have a look at [`pactl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pactl) (or maybe [pacmd](https://askubuntu.com/a/14083/175072) for an interactive interface). Here's a "little" one-liner to set VLC's default level:

```
$ pactl set-sink-input-volume $(pactl list short sink-inputs | grep $(pactl list short clients | grep vlc | cut -f1) | cut -f1) 50%
```

And yes, that's ugly. Basically, I'm getting VLC's index (as a client), and finding the associated sink input's index. Then I inject that index into `set-sink-input-volume`, and set the value to 50%. Have a look at [`pactl(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pactl) for more information about these `pactl` commands. Remember that you can also use `pavucontrol` to configure Pulse in a GUI :)

**If you're using ALSA**, your default volume level is determined using the `alsa-gain` setting in `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc`. For a default volume of `x`, you should set this value to `((x - 0.5) / 100) ^ 3`, since `cbrtf` is a cube root. In your case, that means `alsa-gain = (49.5 / 100) ^ 3 = 0.121287375`. You'll also need to set the `volume-save` setting to 0 (false) in order to apply your new default value every time, regardless of the volume level you were at the last time you closed VLC.